# MySQL Workbench general log. how do we identify a specific user when they made a query across a network?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Under MySQL workbench, I have multiple users connected to the database across a network using rest API.

Whenever they make a change to the database the general log only reports what is being inserted or changed in the database, but it doesn't report who made the changes.

For example, if I try to insert some values into table `person123`, it will only log the following:

```
INSERT INTO  person123 (customerid, firstname, lastname) VALUES ('ya5', 
'yes5', 'yay5')
```

[Image of logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exh1P.jpg)

As you can see it only logs what's being inserted but doesn't let us know who made the query.

Answer (score 0):

> the general log only reports what is being inserted or changed in the database, but it doesnt report from whom the change was made.

In General log you can see the whole session. Like

```
Time                           Id Command    Argument
2021-10-14T15:09:01.830083Z     8 Connect   akina@localhost on test using SSL/TLS
2021-10-14T15:09:01.859920Z     8 Query     select @@version_comment limit 1
2021-10-14T15:09:10.998039Z     8 Query     select version()
2021-10-14T15:09:13.055846Z     8 Quit
```

`Id` column is connection ID. So you can find the Connect row which matches the row with the query in interest and look for the account.